# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - Wired connection detected but Internet not working

Tags: ubuntu, internet-connection, wifi-configuration, ubuntu-16.04

Enable WiFi option not showing at all. And when I tried connecting through USB hotspot from my mobile, it is getting connected but the Internet is not working while it is working pretty well on my mobile. USB hotspot is working fine on Windows 8 installed alongside Ubuntu. I have used USB hotspot from the same mobile before on Ubuntu and it used to work. My hardware is Hp-ac039TU.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your wifi adaptor is blocked by kernel. Open a terminal window, and execute following commands:

`sudo rfkill unblock wifi; sudo rfkill unblock all`

After that, reboot you machine, hopefully it will solve you problem.

Comment: I am not able to connect to internet in any way. It is showing "connection timed out" to both your commands.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by deleting the wired connection. Then Ubuntu just detected it automatically, and that's all.